# Exposing GetEnumerator() for a concurrent dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a concurrent dictionary implementation for C#, and I'm wondering if this `GetEnumerator()` implementation **is actually (thread) safe**.

It's not doing a actual snapshot, so I'm wondering if it'll mess up later read/writes to the internal dictionary, or if it'll expose potential deadlocks because the enumeration of the exposed `IEnumerator` will actually run inside the lock.

```
private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> internalDictionary;
private SpinLock spinLock = new SpinLock();

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator enumerator;

    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        spinLock.TryEnter(ref lockTaken);
        enumerator = (this.internalDictionary as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            spinLock.Exit(false);
        }
    }

    return enumerator;
}
```

Comment: "snapsnot" I hope that's a typo...

Comment: Yeah, but they explicitly advise you not to edit one-letter typos.

Comment: There's no specific problem or question here...

Comment: Highlighted the actual problem in bold. The question is if the implementation is thread-safe.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not thread-safe with respect to concurrent writers because

1. Your enumerator is not snapshotting anything. It is referring back the original dictionary. Call `ToList` on it or something to actually snapshot.
2. Concurrent writers do not use your lock so they execute concurrently. This is unsafe.
3. Don't use a spinlock if the lock body is big.
4. What if TryEnter fails? It is called *try* after all.

Here is a fixed version with all the cleverness removed:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (internalDictionary) return internalDictionary.ToList();
}
```

Concurrent writers have to take the lock, too.

Comment: Yeah, but that *do* return a snapshot ;) As for 3 and 4, that's actually covered by the "lockTaken".

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. Calling GetEnumerator does not snapshot the contents of the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I mentioned in the question that I was aware of it not taking a snapshot.

Comment: So let me answer your question more appropriately: As you're not taking a snapshot, and not locking when reading from the enumerator, you are not thread-safe and are messing up the internal state of the dictionary. And even if locks are taken the enumerator is invalidated by the first write (it will stop working). Does that help?

Comment: That's what I was looking to get confirmed, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The first things that springs to mind is why on earth you would want to create such a beast yourself when .NET ships with thread-safe concurrent collection classes (including a dictionary). Google `System.Collections.Concurrent` for more information.

I've previously benchmarked the ConcurrentDictionary class and I'll guarantee you that they are significantly faster than anything you could write yourself, even when using spin locks or Interlocked to avoid any of the heavier locking mechanisms.

In answer to your question, **maybe, but it depends on the implementation** (which is never a good thing). I'd guess that any write attempts would fail, since the standard collection classes cannot be modified while being iterated; but I wouldn't rely on any such mechanism to keep my own code safe.

Comment: And the obvious answer to *why*, is that ConcurrentDictionary isn't supported on all .NET platforms. As for the answer, that's a reasonable reason for not exposing a enumerator at all, but instead only offer snapshots via. regular Keys/Values properties.

Comment: @Claus Indeed. I'd recommend studying the API surface of the ConcurrentDictionary, even if you are unable to use the implementation, as I'm sure MS has considered the same issues. Maybe you could use C5? It's a very comprehensive and afaik thread-safe library of data structures (collections, trees, etc.). See http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/ for details.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen It looks like the C5 collections are also not thread safe by default. Instead, I can offer you an implementation of a thread-safe dictionary that uses Interlocked, which I wrote for the Fasterflect library. Code can be found at http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41eae592599b#Fasterflect/Fasterflect/Caching/Cache.cs (scroll down to the #elif DOT_NET_35 line). It may not have all you need but provides a decent starting point. Also, it uses Interlocked and is therefore reasonably fast.